# Inserting PHP code inside JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849812/php-in-javascript)

I need to check an if condition inside the inner html property of javascript. And  so for that I need to use php inside it. So is it possible. I tried the following and it doesn't seem to work.

```
document.getElementById().innerHTML = 
    "<?php if ($number == 1) { echo $ex; } else { echo $ey; } ?>";
```

So please help me out with this problem.

Comment: You are misunderstanding how PHP and JavaScript work. PHP works on server side, before the HTML document is created; JavaScript works in the browser, after the HTML document has been generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your PHP is **executed at the server**. Once the page has been fetched, inserting PHP code into it at the client end via JavaScript, **will not** cause it to be executed.

You should store `$number`, `$ex`, `$ey` in JavaScript variables and perform the same comparison in JavaScript.

Firstly,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var number = <? echo $number ?>
var ex = <? echo $ex ?>
var ey = <? echo $ey ?>
</script>
```

The above sets the values of JS variables.
Afterwards, you can call:

```
if (number == 1) { document.getElementById().innerHTML = ex; }
```

Comment: so is there any other alternative to what I should do ?

Comment: C'mon this more a comment than an answer. Please don't answer to these kind of bogus questions where it's clear the OP is asking about misconceptions.

Comment: @Srivathsan: You are invited to use the search before asking any question. That's what we call "do your homework" and it's outlined in the "[ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice)" you needed to confirm before asking any question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php 
if ($number == 1){ ?>
 document.getElementById().innerHTML = $ex;
<?php }
else
    { ?>
 document.getElementById().innerHTML = $ey;
<?php } ?>
```