# Using PHP inside Javascript? To shrink URL

Tags: php, javascript

I made a bitly url shrinker, and I currently have a Soundcloud Javascript API that outputs a url link of a song. Im trying to shrink it using my shrinker. The shrinker works using this:

```
<?php echo $bitly->shorten('http://google.com'); ?> //Equals google.com in short url format
```

The javascript code I'm trying to implement it in is this: Ill go ahead and give you what I tried to do already, that didn't work.

Before I edited:

```
 container.find('span.player-actions').html(
                '<a href="' + track.user.permalink_url + '" target="_blank">Soundcloud</a> | <a href="' + track.permalink_url + '/download" target="_blank">Download</a>'
        );
```

After I tried:

```
container.find('span.player-actions').html(
                '<a href="' +  <?php echo $bitly->shorten('track.user.permalink_url'); ?> + '" target="_blank">Soundcloud</a> | <a href="' + track.permalink_url + '/download" target="_blank">Download</a>'
        );
```

Any suggestions, I'm open to anything. And would love to make this work!

Comment: JavaScript is executed at the client-end. PHP code runs at the server. You **can't** put PHP into your JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849812/php-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

That has been already explained but in case you're new to this concept, there is a simplified explanation.

`<?php` tags in your code are processed on server *before* your page is sent to user's browser. Actually browser never receives those tags - they're replaced with PHP output on server and then the resulting page is sent to user.

As a result of some mistake sometimes PHP code makes into user's browser but it behaves as any other non-standard tag - content between `<?php` and `?>` would be invisible to visitor.

JavaScript, on the other hand, operates in user browser with (in our case) what PHP has already output. When you change the page with JavaScript, it's not sent back to server - actually, server is totally unaware of that, so it can't execute the PHP code you're outputting by your JavaScript.

In order to achieve a similar result you need to send an AJAX request from your JavaScript code. It'll basically be another "page request" initiated by your JavaScript, but happening at the background with PHP output not replacing your current page, but arriving into your JavaScript code. This way your JavaScript is outputting PHP *output* and not PHP *code*, that's why it is possible.

Comment: Thank you Yuriy! That was the explanation I was looking for! Spot on

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please mark one of the answers you received for this question as accepted if it is now clear to you? That's the way this site works.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call PHP on a string that is generated via javascript since PHP is server side and executed before JavaScript which is client side.

If you want to shorten this string, you'll have to make an ajax call to a php page that will return the shrunk url.